# Scroll bars for divs

Tags: css

```
 <div name="qst" id="qst" style='width:60%;float:left;display:inline;overflow:auto;'> </div>
 <div id="data" name="data" class='checkbox' style='overflow:hidden;width:35%;height:550px;margin-left:0px;'></div>
```

These two div appears one beside the other.How to get the scroll bars for both divs.The data is loaded dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the overflow on the second div to be auto instead of hidden, if that's an option.

Comment: What Gabe said ... also ...

This might seem obvious, but you will need to set the height of the first container as well.